# Telerik Kendo UI for JQuery Gantt Configuration for Angular 7 Web Application

Tags: jquery, angular, kendo-ui

I am developing an Angular 7 web application which implements Angular Material controls throughout. I now need to include a Kendo UI for JQuery Gantt Chart. There appears to be two approaches to configuring this:

1. Copy the `js` and the `styles` folders from the Kendo UI for JQuery installation directory into my `wwwroot` folder and reference them in my `index.html` file.
2. `npm install --save @progress/kendo-ui` and `npm install --save @progress/kendo-theme-material`.

With approach 1, manually copying the folders into `wwwroot` the `js folder is approximately 77Mb and the`styles` folder approximately 20Mb. I don't want to be deploying these for every release.

With approach 2, `npm install...` my webpack bundled `main.js` file is approximately 5.5Mb which is better, but on inspection still contains the entire Kendo UI suite of components when I only need the Gantt and it's dependant components. I also found that when I `npm install...` the Material theme and include a reference in my `angular.json` file, the styling on the components appears incorrect. The bars are coloured but almost everything else has no colour and the Gantt chart doesn't resize properly.

My compromise has been to use the `npm install...` for the Kendo UI components and manually copy the required `.css` files into my `wwwroot` folder and reference them in my `index.html` file.

Can anyone suggest a better approach for a lean, robust way of implementing these Gantt controls please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had to use the jQuery Gantt chart in a Angular 7 project.
I also took the second approach:

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-ui
```

Then I inserted the following statement in my `app.module.ts`:

```
import '@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.gantt'
```

My bundled `main.js` is 79kb big.

If you need any more information, feel free to respond.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I didn't realise I could be more specific, that's very helpful thank you. I removed the `js` folder from `wwwroot` and left the `styles` folder in. I deleted all css styles except for the common material and the material files. This helps but the DejaVu fonts are approx 7Mb. Can these be trimmed in any way?